# How to connect a database on other computer by IP?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a SQL database located on a computer which is in another location and  that computer has a static IP.
What is the correct connection string I must use to connect to that database?
I tried this string:

```
"Data Source=\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Network Library=DBMSSOCN ;Initial Catalog=mydb; User ID=username; Password=mypassword"
```

Comment: Please do refer to `www.connectionstrings.com` . Is the other computer behind a router ? Do check that the router allow the connections

Comment: @Ayden, remove the leading backslash before the IP address. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx for the authoritative reference for SqlClient connection string keywords.

Comment: thank you all, but where is the place that i should put the login info to the system (windows 7)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this connection string. May be it helps you.

```
Server=568.45.45.46;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: this is to connect to the server and login to SQL server , so what about the login info to the system (windows 7)

Comment: This is using mixed-mode authentication, so you don't need to have a Windows login on the database server.

Comment: @Ayden If now you able to connect your database. Mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  dim constr As String = "data source=IPAdresse;initial catalog=mydb;User Id=username;Password=pwd
```